# Groovy: Navigating a empty xml

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper

Reading xml from flat file and parsing it using XmlSlurper. Here is how XML file look like

```
<ClientInformation>
<ContractClientVO>
 <AssignmentReasonCT></AssignmentReasonCT>
 <Associated></Associated>
 <AuthorizedSignatureCT></AuthorizedSignatureCT>
 <ClassCT></ClassCT>
 <RelationshipToInsuredCT></RelationshipToInsuredCT>
 <RelationshipToEmployeeCT></RelationshipToEmployeeCT>
 <ClientRoleVO>
  <AgentFK></AgentFK>
  <Associated></Associated>
  <RoleTypeCT></RoleTypeCT>
  <ClientDetailVO>
    <address></address>
    <city></city>
    <state></state>
    <Amount></Amount>
  </ClientDetailVO>
 </ClientRoleVO>
</ContractClientVO>
</ClientInformation>
```

XmlSlurper reads it fine and prints the XML document. But it does not navigate XML elements.

```
def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(file)
println XmlUtil.serialize(xml) //outputs fine on console
println xml.ClientInformation.size() //outputs 0
```

Comment: Fixed the xml for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example (once you fix the xml to be valid), the variable `xml` represents the root node of the document `ClientInformation`

So calling:

```
xml.ClientInformation
```

Returns nothing (as `ClientInformation` doesn't have a child called `ClientInformation`)

To get the number of children of the root document tag, you need to just do:

```
println xml.size()
```

Comment: By the time I finish my coffee, you moved my cheese... :P

Comment: Don't worry. Working on a big Xml Transformation piece and I am new to groovy.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav One small piece of suggestion, you can search your question in SO then you can post one, if you do not find any solution. I bet you will find one of Tim's answer. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Yes. I do a lot of google search before posting a question on SO. Being new to Groovy most of the questions will specific to groovy concepts.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Was this the answer?  Or did I miss a part of the question? :-)  Hope it's working!

Comment: @tim_yates Everything is fine. Thanks for asking.